# Passing a checkbox input from PHP to JavsScript

Tags: javascript, php

How can I pass a value of check box from PHP to Javascript :-

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root1") or die (mysql_error ());
            mysql_select_db("quiz") or die(mysql_error());
            $strSQL = "SELECT name,score,team FROM login ORDER BY name";
            $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) 
    {
    $man = $row['name'];
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$row['name'].'|'.$row['score'].'|'.$row['team'].'" class="chkbox"  name="checkbox1[]" onchange="check(this)" />';  
    echo $man;
    echo "<br>";
    }
<?
```

I want to pass the values of team of each checkbox selected to a JS funtion called check.

Answer (score -1):

You have passed `this` to the function check() so you can access all its attributes of the (input - checkbox) element using `.`.

```
function check(Obj){  
    alert(Obj.value);
}
```

Please read about [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) Javascript keyword.

Comment: I'll be passing each the value of each check box using 'this', I am aware of this keyword.

Comment: strange ppl put a downvote but cannot afford to put a comment !!

Comment: `type=checkbox` input field uses attribute `checked="true"` is checked or `checked` and not `value`.